# Find/query only records which has associated records (1:n)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any possibility to query only the records which has associated records? For sure I can find first all the records in the store and filter this records afterwards, but I wonder if there is a more "Ember" way of doing this.

**Use case:**

There are customers which has projects. I want to find only the customers which actually has projects.

**Code**

How can I replace/extend this snippet to get this working?

```
this.store.find('customer').then(function(customers) {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findQuery`. (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/f8f3fbc6ff7e7e9549f19ae8b544fe53f18ca3fc/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L180)

Example:

```
this.store.findQuery('customer', { hasProjects: true }).then(function(customersThatHaveProjects) {
  # ...
});
```

This way you can have the server decide which records to send back instead of (needlessly) sending *all* customer objects.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, but do you have an answer to this (related) question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905772/catch-404-error-when-using-store-findquery

Comment: I've taken a look, glad to help out;)