# Catch 404 error when using store.findQuery

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Embers `findQuery` method and wonder how to catch 404 errors when there are no results?

```
this.store.findQuery('customer', { hasProjects: true, getArchivedProjects: archived }).then(function(customers) {
});
```

If the query is empty, the code inside this `then` function doesn't get fired, so I can't even check the type of `customers`.

**Example:**

```
this.store.findQuery('customer', { hasProjects: true, getArchivedProjects: archived }).then(function(customers) {
  console.log('foo')
});
```

If the query returns a 404, `console.log` doesn't be fired.

Comment: normally another function inside "then("

Comment: I updated my question. Actually, the code inside the `then` function doesn't get fired if the query returns a 404

Comment: first function is onsuccess, second function should be error handler which should handle 404. but I am not sure with ember-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The findQuery function returns a promise.  You may then provide two functions to the then(), the first being the success path, the second being the failure path...  for example:

```
this.store.findQuery('customer', { hasProjects: true, getArchivedProjects: archived }).then(function(customers) {
    console.log('foo')
}, function(error) { /* do something with error */ });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I tried `..., function(error) { console.log('bar'); });` and my console is empty.

Comment: OK, sounds like you have other issues, based on your other comments ('i don't use the model hook').

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it's an issue. The problem I tried to solve (get nested records with associations + filtering & sorting) seems to be very tricky and some Ember "specialists" has advised to solve it this way. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative answer:

Add a `error` hook to the corresponding route:

```
App.CustomersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    error: function(reason) {
      if (reason.status === 404) {
        // do something ...
      }
    }
  }
})
```

See: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_when-promises-reject.

Comment: It should work, just tried it out. You'll need to use the model hook in the route though

Comment: Ah, I don't use the model hook, I have a function in my controller that gets called by the route. I need this function in my controller, because other functions have to call it (I'm building a complex array with filtered, sorted and nested records), so I have to call it sometimes for rerendering. Are there any options to solve it without using the model hook?

Comment: Yeah, you could override ajaxError on the `ApplicationAdapter`. Be sure to call _super though. You might wanna look into setupController however, seems like you're not doing it The Ember Way (tm). But i might be wrong;)

Comment: Thanks, but I got the code from Steve H. working. I played a while around with your snippet, but I think it just does not work in my special case. Thank you anyway!